# Why do you have to be buried after dying from a vampire bite to become a vampire spawn?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead, lore

The [vampire](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/vampire)'s bite attack states that if bitten and the target dies because of the bite and is buried in the ground only then can they turn into a vampire spawn under the control of the vampire:

> *Hit:* 7 (1d6 + 4) piercing damage plus 10 (3d6) necrotic damage. The target's hit point maximum is reduced by an amount equal to the necrotic damage taken, and the vampire regains hit points equal to that amount. The reduction lasts until the target finishes a long rest. The target dies if this effect reduces its hit point maximum to 0. **A humanoid slain in this way and then buried in the ground rises the following night as a vampire spawn under the vampire's control.**

But do you really have to be buried? I get that if you get cremated you won't rise as a pile of ash with a thirst for blood, but it seems odd that being buried is a requirement to come back as a vampire spawn.

**What is the in-universe (lore) reason why humanoids killed by a vampire's bite must be buried in order to rise as a vampire spawn?**

Comment: I don't really see how this question makes more sense than "why are vampires harmed by sunlight" or "why can't vampires cross running water". That's just how they work in D&D. Is there a particular problem you experience with requiring victims to be buried?

Comment: @Theik No problem, happy to work with it, but it just seems odd that being buried is a requirement. What if you're left to die in the woods, why would you not then become a vampire spawn? The reason I believe this to be different to the rules you mentioned is because this is the first time I'm hearing this. Not once have I seen a movie or read a book where being buried is a requirement, so I'd like to know why the writers of D&D chose this.

Comment: If you want to know why the writers made this decision, then that's a designer-reasons question and it is not on topic for the stack - such questions almost never get good answers.

Comment: @Carcer I did not know this, thank you. I'll make sure not to ask such questions in the future.

Comment: I've edited out the designer-reasons portion of the question and focused it just on the lore reason.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Vampires are "chained to the grave"

As clarified in the earlier descriptive text at the start of the [*Monster Manual* entry on vampires](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/mm/monsters-v#Vampires) (p. 295), vampires and vampire spawn are bound to their sites of burial or entombment:

> ***Chained to the Grave.*** Every vampire remains bound to its coffin, crypt, or grave site, where it must rest by day. If a vampire didn’t receive a formal burial, it must lie beneath a foot of earth at the place of its transition to undeath. A vampire can move its place of burial by transporting its coffin or a significant amount of grave dirt to another location. Some vampires set up multiple resting places this way.

The vampire's grave site and burial are metaphysically significant to their nature - a vampire cannot exist without a grave of some kind that acts as its resting place, from which it ventures at night and returns to during the day. A creature killed by a vampire's bite who does not receive a deliberate burial will not become a vampire spawn unless "naturally" buried somehow - such as by a landslide or cave-in. Either way, they *must* be in conditions that could be described as a grave or tomb in order to raise as a vampire.

The "*Stake to the Heart*" weakness that vampires and vampire spawn have specifically references their resting place:

> ***Vampire Weaknesses.*** The vampire has the following flaws:
>
> [...]
>
> - *Stake to the Heart.* If a piercing weapon made of wood is driven into the vampire's heart while the vampire is incapacitated in its resting place, the vampire is paralyzed until the stake is removed.

And the vampire spawn version:

> - *Stake to the Heart.* The vampire is destroyed if a piercing weapon made of wood is driven into its heart while it is incapacitated in its resting place.

Vampire spawn, though less powerful than "true" vampires and slaved to their master's will, are still vampires with normal vampiric strengths and weaknesses, and they still require a grave of some kind to rest in.

Comment: Being left somewhere and then having earth blown over you creates a makeshift grave, I assume, but it's hardly a "formal burial".

Comment: Yeah, I would probably rule that's sufficiently grave-like to count.

Comment: Awesome! This makes sense for the Vampire, but does a Vampire Spawn also have this trait (or is this vampire monster race bound)? I don't have my MM on me at the moment, but a simple yes/no would suffice. I'll make sure to read the vampires over again tonight :P

Comment: @ThomasYates Vampire spawn are a subentry of the vampire and the same overall description applies. They also have the "stake to the heart" weakness referencing their resting place (except that when a lowly vampire spawn gets staked, it is destroyed rather than paralysed like a true vampire).

Comment: May be worth pointing out that these vampire traits are very roughly based on common western mythology (a mythology that has evolved over time). Other cultures have vampires or vampire-like creatures with very different strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: @ThomasYates: Vampire spawn are still a type of vampire; as the prior section of the entry notes, "Most of a vampire’s victims become vampire spawn — ravenous creatures with a vampire’s hunger for blood, but under the control of the vampire that created them." It then describes "true vampires" as those freed from this control; otherwise, vampire spawn still have the same vampiric traits described in the MM entry (outside the statblock) as a true vampire.

Comment: Actually I'm second-guessing my interpretation of that "formal burial" line now. Should it be read to mean that a vampire that was created without a grave just has to dig a hole a foot deep on the spot it was created in order to rest, or that *it does not become a vampire in the first place* until at least a foot of dirt is on top of it?

Comment: And if it's the former, that would mean that it's not required to be buried to become a vampire. If I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I think I misunderstood it on the first go and it's actually meant to mean the latter - that would be more consistent (and Create Undead can't create vampires arbitrarily like I thought it could, which was why that could have been important). Editing...

Comment: Hm.. now I wonder, what happens if the burial place is destroyed? Let's say it's a wooden coffin that's been burnt to ash, and avoid the endless supply of dirt if it was a simple hole in the ground :P

Comment: Well, they can always return to the actual site of the grave, even if you've removed the grave soil.  It may be theoretically possible to do something to make the site unusable, like scouring it down to bedrock, in which case I suppose they'd be exposed to sunlight and die from that, rather than directly because the grave was destroyed.  It's generally easier to locate their resting place during the day and bring sunlight into it (possibly along with destroying their other resting places so you know where they'll be).

Comment: Interestingly there doesn't appear to be a time limit imposed between the death and the burial...  So what happens when the poor adventurer's bones get buried by a landslide after lying on the surface for a decade in some secluded area?